# Change Border color of floating form in react bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

How can i change that blue border color?? (React Bootstrap)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem [your color];` property

Answer (score 0):

use `box-shadow` property

```
element{
  box-shadow: hertical, horizontal, blur, color;
}
```

- First Connect your bootstrap
- Create a '*.css' file add your changes
- Last Connect your custom css file to the project.